# Why do I stay logged in on Stack Overflow but always need to login to Programmers?

Tags: support, login

I rarely if ever need to log in to Stack Overflow. It remembers me.

I always have to log in to Programmers. Yes, it's not too hard because I can log in with my SO credentials, but it's one extra step and 3 clicks every single time. Why is that? What can I do to stayed logged in, if anything?

Browser: Firefox
OS: Windows 8

Comment: I suspect cookies. If your cookie or localstorage settings for [so] and [programmers.se] differ, that could explain it.

Comment: @hims056: No, that was definitely not the answer. Like I said, I read those posts.

Comment: @michaelb958: Why didn't I think of that? You got it. I must have changed the cookie settings for SO years ago, before Programmers even exists. Thanks for the tip. You get the tick, if you want one.

Comment: Agreed, my mistake as well. Voted to reopen, then @michaelb958 can post it as answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reopen. Would you believe this went from a minus to a 'Nice Question' badge in an instant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess in the comments (which turned out to be the solution) was that your cookie settings for Stack Overflow differed from your cookie settings for Programmers. SE network authentication is powered by cookies; if a site is not permitted to retain cookies, you won't stay logged in on that site.

To fix, simply let `stackexchange.com` (of which Programmers is a subdomain) store cookies. While you're at it, you might also want to whitelist `superuser.com`, `serverfault.com`, `askubuntu.com`, and `mathoverflow.net`, those being the other SE-operated domains (it seems you've already whitelisted `stackoverflow.com`).

Comment: What I missed of course is that the sites have different domains and therefore different cookie settings in Firefox. Thanks for reopening -- someone else may benefit from this.